# Algo equivalente a biblioteca sstream do C++ para C

Tags: mysql, c, c++, string, char

Preciso de algo parecido com as stringstream que tem na liguagem C++ para a linguagem C, necessito muito disso pois pretendo realiza querys em um banco de dados usando C (C mysql connector).

Como não tinha ideia de algo parecido com oque tinha na biblioteca sstream para C eu pensei em usar strncat, mais não saiu como o previsto, observe:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char username[25];
    char passwd[45];

    printf("Input your name ->");
    fgets(username, 25, stdin);

    printf("Input your password->");
    fgets(passwd, 45, stdin);

    char query[128]="select username, password from accounts where username='";
    char and[18]="' and password='";

    strncat(query, username, 25);
    strncat(query, and, 16);
    strncat(query, passwd, 45);
    strncat(query, "';\n", 4);

    printf("%s", query);

    return 0;

    //OBS: Código de exemplo
}
```

Quando rodo o programa:

```
gcc main.c
./a.out
Input your name ->linus
Input your password->123
select username, password from accounts where username='linus
' and password='123
';
```

Observe que ele pulou uma linha e deu uns espaços e isso em uma query poderia gerar erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o `fgets` também lê o `\n` e armazena no *buffer* de leitura. Pode resolver isto removendo manualmente o `\n` que foi o ultimo caretere lido:

```
fgets(username, 25, stdin);
size_t ultima_pos = strlen(username) - 1;
if (username[ultima_pos] == '\n'){
    username[ultima_pos] = '\0'; //terminar a string no local onde está o `\n`
}
```

De forma a não ter que repetir esta lógica para todas as leituras, sugiro que a abstraia através de uma função de leitura:

```
void ler_string(char *destino, size_t tamanho){
    fgets(destino, tamanho, stdin);
    size_t ultima_pos = strlen(destino) - 1;
    if (destino[ultima_pos] == '\n'){
        destino[ultima_pos] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Chamando-a assim:

```
ler_string(username, 25);
```

Para o que está a tentar construir torna-se bem mais simples de interpolar os valores que quer dentro da `string` utilizando [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/), o que evita ter que fazer várias concatenações:

```
sprintf(query,"select username, password from accounts where username='%s' and password='%s'\n", username, passwd);
```

Juntando tudo isso o seu programa ficaria assim:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void ler_string(char *destino, size_t tamanho){
    fgets(destino, tamanho, stdin);
    size_t ultima_pos = strlen(destino) - 1;
    if (destino[ultima_pos] == '\n'){
        destino[ultima_pos] = '\0';
    }
}

int main(){
    char username[25];
    char passwd[45];

    printf("Input your name ->");
    ler_string(username, 25);

    printf("Input your password->");
    ler_string(passwd, 45);

    char query[128];
    sprintf(query,"select username, password from accounts where username='%s' and password='%s'\n", username, passwd);
    printf("%s", query);

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja a sua execução no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ReewqH)

**Nota**:

Recomendo que tome atenção a ataques de MySQL injection, que é algo que está susceptivel com essa aproximação sem controlar o input que o usuário dá no programa.

Comment: Não seria melhor só por via das dúvidas verificar se a entrada foi uma linha inteira? Se for uma entrada truncada (alcançou EOF, por exemplo), eu tenho a impressão que o último caracter não seria `\n`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim de facto seria jogar pelo seguro. Também concordo que é melhor. Vou editar

Comment: @Isac Exatamente dessas informações que eu precisava. Thanks!