# caracteres e tabela ASCII

Tags: c, string, ascii

Estou tentando realizar um exercício do URI ,e na 1 parte ele pede o seguinte:

> Na primeira passada, somente caracteres que sejam letras minúsculas e
>   maiúsculas devem ser deslocadas 3 posições para a direita, segundo a
>   tabela ASCII: letra 'a' deve virar letra 'd', letra 'y' deve virar
>   caractere '|' e assim sucessivamente

Porem ele também esta alterando os que não sai letras minúsculas e maiúsculas ,não sei porque esta acontecendo isso,agradeço quem poder ajudar.

Por exemplo:
com entrada `texto #3` devia sair `wh{wr #3` ,porem ta saindo  `wh{wr <`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char x[10],y[10];
int i,qnt;
fgets(x,sizeof(x),stdin);
qnt = strlen(x);

 /********   1 PASSADA  ************/
 for(i = 0;i<qnt;i++){
    if (((x[i]>=65) && (x[i]<=90))  || ((x[i]>=97) && (x[i]<=122)) )
            y[i]=x[i]+3;
            printf("%d %d , %c \n",i,y[i],y[i]);
 }

 printf("tamanho da string %i \n",qnt);

 printf("normal %d , %s\n",x,x);
  printf("1 passada  , %s \n",y);

 printf("normal %d , %s\n",x,x);
 for(i = 0;i<qnt;i++){
    printf("%d %d , %c \n",i,x[i],x[i]);

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade o programa não está a colocar valores para quando não é uma letra, apanhando assim o valor por defeito que estiver no vetor `y`.

Altere o seu `for` para:

```
for(i = 0; i<qnt; i++)
{
    if (((x[i]>=65) && (x[i]<=90))  || ((x[i]>=97) && (x[i]<=122)) )
        y[i]=x[i]+3;
    else //faltou este else
        y[i]=x[i]; //que atribui o valor original quando não é letra

    printf("%d %d , %c \n",i,y[i],y[i]);
}
```

[Confirme no Ideone que já obtem a saida esperada](https://ideone.com/1eIxGk)

Algumas observações que deixo:

- Se tem o `main` como `int` deve colocar o valor de retorno no final com `return 0;` indicando que o programa terminou com sucesso
- Colocar o valor ascii das letras diretamente é prejudicial à leitura do código. Ao invés disso deve colocar a letra como `char`. Logo o `if` dentro do `for` seria melhor escrito assim:

  ```
  if ((x[i]>='A' && x[i]<='Z')  || (x[i]>='a' && x[i]<='z') )
      y[i]=x[i]+3;
  ```
- Em `printf("normal %d , %s\n",x,x);` está a imprimir a `string` `x` como um inteiro com `%d` que não faz sentido.
- O `fgets` deixa-lhe um `\n` no fim da leitura dentro da `string`. Se não o quiser ou for imperativo que não o tenha, remova-o. [Pode ver nesta minha outra resposta como faze-lo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/279709/algo-equivalente-a-biblioteca-sstream-do-c-para-c/279712#279712).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta rapida!!.
irei fazer as alterações,em relação ao printf imprindo a string com %d eu coloquei apenas para ver como era /se era possivel.
Muito obrigado pelas dicas.